# Regex for finding first x occurrences of alphabetical characters, ignoring everything else

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I'm trying to write a Regex for matching the first 2 alphabetical characters appearing anywhere in a string. So far I haven't been able to achieve the results I want.

The attempts I have made so far have mainly consisted of trying to group anything matching `A-Za-z`, `\w`, etc. but with every attempt, I have either caught parentheses, brackets or been stopped due to either whitespace or symbols in between the two alphabetical characters.

I don't care about anything other than the characters, and I could code my way out this easily, but I really want to learn how to do this with regular expressions.

**My attempts:**

`[(A-Za-z)]{2}` - Fails since it includes `()` and `(U` for some reason that I cannot figure out.

`[A-z].*[A-z]` - Matches everything between the characters

`[A-z]?[A-z]` - Seems to catch some of the stuff I wanted but unfortunately also catches brackets and some weird behaviour in test #2.

`[A-Za-z]{2}` - Catches the first two connected alphabetical characters but misses anything that contains anything in between.

`[A-Za-z](?:)[A-Za-z]` - Catches connected alphabetical characters but not split ones.

I think my main problem is that I don't know how to make the regular expression ignore anything in between the two alphabetical symbols without including them in my match.

I have looked through the wiki, regex101, regexone, regexr, regular-expressions.info and reference, but I simply cannot seem to figure out how to do this. I am using the Regex engine in Google's BigQuery

**Tests:**

---

1. `USUK`

Should match exactly `US`

---

2. `123U456 KUS`

Should match exactly `UK`

---

3. `[]() [][(UK]) ( ) [ ] US`

Should match exactly `UK`

---

4. `]-u K[`

Should match exactly `uK`

---

Thanks for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: You could use 2 capturing groups and match the whitespace chars in between `\b([a-zA-Z])\s*([a-zA-Z])` https://regex101.com/r/e18y4F/1 Or only match and remove the whitespaces after `\b[a-zA-Z]\s*[a-zA-Z]`  https://regex101.com/r/SXDPnQ/1 Note that there is no `UK` in `KUS` is that a typo?

Comment: @Thefourthbird there is a "U" inside the numbers in test #2. It should get that and the K from `KUS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(col, r'^[^A-Za-z]*([A-Za-z])[^A-Za-z]*([A-Za-z]).*', r'\1\2')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1UNNoO/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^A-Za-z]*` - 0 or more chars other than ASCII letters
- `([A-Za-z])` - Group 1 (`\1`): an ASCII letter
- `[^A-Za-z]*` - 0 or more chars other than ASCII letters
- `([A-Za-z])` - Group 2 (`\2`): an ASCII letter
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

Comment: This seems very long for what I am trying to achieve, but it seems to do the trick! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think below approach is much cleaner and easy to comprehend

```
SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(col, r'[^A-Za-z]', ''), 1, 2)
```

In above  - you first simply eliminating all non alphabetical characters by replacing them with empty string
And then you just take first two chars

Comment: I provided this answer as a follow up on your `... seems very long for what I am trying to achieve ... ` comment to Wiktor's otherwise excellent answer